# Modal JQuery-UI Dialog with NicEdit issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, nicedit

I've got a JQuery Modal Dialog with a NicEdit editor in it.
The NicEditor has an HTML button that allows the user to adjust the HTML directly.
Outside of the Modal Dialogue this works fine.
However inside of the modal dialog it won't stay open.

I've replicated this in a Plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/kr6GAS4Z0SNh6Ws38WdO?p=preview

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="dialog" title="test" style="display:none;">
    <form>
        <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
<input type="button" id="test" value="open dialog wysiwyg"/>    
  </body>
<script>
  $('#test').click(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        width:400,
        height:400,
        modal:true,
        open: function(){
            new nicEditor({ minHeight: 220, maxHeight: 220, fullPanel: true, iconsPath:'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/nicedit/0.9r24/nicEditorIcons.gif'}).panelInstance('editor');
        }
    });


});

</script>
</html>
```

Is there any way this can be made to work?

Comment: I believe the issue stems from NicEdit not placing the edit pane in the dialog itself - I think it's attached to the main body.

Turning modal off resolves the problem - although ideally I want it on!

Answer (score 0):

Suspect it's an order of operations issue. Try this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/pEFjSYhCem5TFkUeunvt?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>
    <!-- Title here -->
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./nicedit.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
  <div id="dialog">
    <textarea id="editorInDialog"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="test" value="open modal dialog" />
  <script>
    $('#test').click(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
    $('#dialog').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      open: function() {
        new nicEditor({
          fullPanel: true,
          iconsPath: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/nicedit/0.9r24/nicEditorIcons.gif'
        }).panelInstance('editorInDialog');
      }
    });

    new nicEditor({
      fullPanel: true,
      iconsPath: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/nicedit/0.9r24/nicEditorIcons.gif'
    }).panelInstance('editor');
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This seems to exhibit the same issue. Clicking on the HTML button causes the HTML editor to open... but clicking in the editor causes it to close again.

Comment: So this specific issue I suspect is sort of a stacking / element focus issue. The HTML "dialog" appears in a usable space, but when attempting to click on it, or interact with it, it closes itself. I wonder if the `z-index` of this needs to be higher than the overlay, like 1003 in this case.

Comment: It seems to get `z-index` of 9999 when it opens. More investigation to be done.